# Re-arranging a single column of strings based on text containing different dates, by date

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am looking to arrange a dataframe by dates, however, the dates are a part of a string within each row. The rows must be rearranged in order by day.

Other solutions from stack overflow show how to sort based on a column of dates alone, this example is different because other information is a part of each string and is mixed with the dates.

The dataframe is one column with an index, but the rows are not arranged in  order from the dates contained on the far right side of each string.
The score numbers are random and do not require any attention.

```
                        0
__________________________
0     score17 6-20-19.xlsx
1     score23 6-7-19.xlsx
2     score4  6-17-19.xlsx      
3     score34 6-8-19.xlsx
4     score10 6-7-19.xlsx
```

The expected dataframe should look like this (repeated dates have no preference for order between each other and index doesn't matter). The respective scores must stay with their associated dates.

```
                         0
__________________________
1     score23 6-7-19.xlsx
4     score10 6-7-19.xlsx
3     score34 6-8-19.xlsx
2     score4  6-17-19.xlsx
0     score17 6-20-19.xlsx
```

What is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat crude way using common string expressions to create a few columns, then sort accordingly.

First, I'd suggest "stripping" your column to ensure leading/lagging whitespace is not an issue, your example hand non standard spacing.

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.strip()
```

You can then split your column at the first "space" (' ') like so, note this creates two columns:

```
df[['score', 'date']] = df['column_name'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

You can then split your "date" column at the period ('.') to get rid of the extension:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.split('.', expand = True)
```

Then cast that "date" column as datetime:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Now you can sort your dataframe based on this "date" column, setting ascending = True/False based on your desired format.

```
df.sort_values(by='date', ascending = False)
```

Comment: This got me really close to what was needed. An additional argument "inplace = True" was needed for the df.sort_values function.

Comment: as a modification to this, I created one new column to the existing data by only extracting the date. From that, I was able to sort the rows using the pandas smart date conversion (and the inplace = True argument). Lastly, I defined the new dataframe as the newly sorted "0" column.